# How to define optional foreign key in Slick?

Tags: scala, slick

I have a table like this:

```
object Addresses extends Table[AddressRow]("address") {
   def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def street = column[String]("street")
  def number = column[String]("number")
  def zipcode = column[String]("zipcode")
  def city = column[String]("city")
  def country = column[String]("country")
  def geoLocationId = column[Int]("geo_location_id", O.Nullable)

 // Foreign keys.
 def geoLocation = foreignKey("fk_geo_location", geoLocationId, GeoLocations)(_.id)

 // Rest of my code.
 ...
}
```

where my case class is:

```
case class AddressRow(
  id: Option[Int] = None,
  street: String,
  number: String,
  zipcode: String,
  city: String,
  country: String,
  geoLocationId: Option[Int])
```

As you notice geoLocation is an optional foreign key....

I can't find any way to describe this "Optional" in my foreign key definition.

I've tried like:

```
  def geoLocation = foreignKey("fk_geo_location", geoLocationId.asColumnOf[Option[Int]], GeoLocations)(_.id)
```

but I receive:

> Caused by: scala.slick.SlickException: Cannot use column Apply
>   Function Cast in foreign key constraint (only named columns are
>   allowed)

Does anybody has a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that what you are trying to do is accomplishable by using foreign keys. 
Check out  [joining](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.0/lifted-embedding.html#joining-and-zipping) and [user defined types](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.0/lifted-embedding.html#user-defined-functions-and-types) from the Slick docs.

Note the example with the `leftJoin`:

```
val explicitLeftOuterJoin = for {
  (c, s) <- Coffees leftJoin Suppliers on (_.supID === _.id)
} yield (c.name, s.name.?)
```

So if you wanted to query for all of your `Addresses`, you'd want to start with something like

```
val addressGeolocQuery = for {
  (addr, loc) <- Addresses leftJoin GeoLocations on (_.geoLocationId === _.id)
} yield addr.id ~ loc.prop1.? ~ loc.prop2.? /*and so on*/
```

You could then map the results of that query so that you get back an actual `Address` instance, complete with an `Option[GeoLocation]`. That's why I linked the "user defined types" in the docs... that's a new feature to me (I was familiar with ScalaQuery, which was Slick's previous incarnation), but it looks fairly promising.

Answer (score 20):

Try The following:

```
def geoLocationId = column[Option[Int]]("geo_location_id")
//Foreign Key
def geoLocation = foreignKey("fk_geo_location", geoLocationId, GeoLocations)(_.id.?)
```

`geoLocationId` is now a Column of `Option[Int]` therefore `O.Nullable` is no longer needed
`(_.id.?)` returns the `GeoLocation` as an option, or `None` if it was null.